# How to hide UITableView before searching anything in search bar in swift

Tags: swift, swift3, uikit

hey can anyone plz help me out that how to hide my table view before searching anything in search bar. In my case, which is a textfield
I tried different methods but nothing is working

here this is my code for search location:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if !searchedArray.isEmpty {
        
        return searchedArray.count
    }
    
    return filtered ? 0 : LocationData.count
}




func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    
    if !searchedArray.isEmpty{
        cell.textLabel?.text = searchedArray[indexPath.row]
    }else{
        cell.textLabel?.text = LocationData[indexPath.row]
    }
   
    return cell
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
   // selectedCell = indexPath
    //tableView.isHidden = true
    searchTextField.text = searchedArray[indexPath.row]
    
}

//mark uitextfield delegates

func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    
    if let text = textField.text {
        //typed text comes here
        filterText(text+string)
    }
   
    
    
    return true
}

func filterText(_ query: String){
    
   
    searchedArray.removeAll()
    
    for str in LocationData {
        if str.lowercased().starts(with: query.lowercased()){
            searchedArray.append(str)
        }
    }
    
    searchTableView.reloadData()
    filtered = true
    

}
```

Also how can I remove extra rows which shown in table view when I search a location

Comment: post full class code

Answer (score 1):

here is how you remove extra cells

```
   func filterText(_ query: String){
        searchedArray = LocationData.filter({$0.lowercased().contains(query.lowercased())})
        searchTableView.reloadData()
        filtered = true
    }
```

if you want to hide tableView

```
 var searchedArray = [YourType]() {
         didSet {
            searchTableView.isHidden = searchedArray.count == 0
        }
    }
```

but I don't think so to hide tableView is better option
in case to show 0 cells tap on search bar textfield

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        self.filtered = true
         self.searchTableView.reloadData()
    }
```